# Alarm Manager sometimes does not trigger

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am running this App which is already on GitHub

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/dacfaec98cf6ddfa587a80a9d9338c14cfb123d1/LocalNotifications

Create notification should schedule a Notification 10 Seconds later, but I notice that sometimes It doesn't trigger. Why is this happening?

Comment: Did you read the AlarmManager documentation? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager Have you tried using SetExact to see if this helps? Have you tried, exempt your App from battery optimizations? If no, did you acquire a Wake Lock?

Comment: Thanks, It's working back now... I'm gonna wait till it fails again.

Comment: Use [`setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) to help trigger the alarm while the device is idle.